# HLS using Nginx RTMP Module not working

Tags: nginx, rtmp, http-live-streaming

So I installed NGINX and the RTMP MODULE on my mac in the  usr/local/nginx location. RTMP stream works fine just not the HLS version. Here is my config file:

```
events {
worker_connections  1024;
}

rtmp {

server {

    listen 1936;

    chunk_size 4000;

    application small {
        live on;
        # Video with reduced resolution comes here from ffmpeg
    }

    # video on demand
    application vod {
        play /var/flvs;
    }

    application vod2 {
        play /var/mp4s;
    }

    # Many publishers, many subscribers
    # no checks, no recording
    application videochat {

        live on;

        # The following notifications receive all
        # the session variables as well as
        # particular call arguments in HTTP POST
        # request

        # Make HTTP request & use HTTP retcode
        # to decide whether to allow publishing
        # from this connection or not
        on_publish http://localhost:8080/publish;

        # Same with playing
        on_play http://localhost:8080/play;

        # Publish/play end (repeats on disconnect)
        on_done http://localhost:8080/done;

        # All above mentioned notifications receive
        # standard connect() arguments as well as
        # play/publish ones. If any arguments are sent
        # with GET-style syntax to play & publish
        # these are also included.
        # Example URL:
        #   rtmp://localhost/myapp/mystream?a=b&c=d

        # record 10 video keyframes (no audio) every 2 minutes
        record keyframes;
        record_path /tmp/vc;
        record_max_frames 10;
        record_interval 2m;

        # Async notify about an flv recorded
        on_record_done http://localhost:8080/record_done;

    }


    # HLS

    # For HLS to work please create a directory in tmpfs (/tmp/hls here)
    # for the fragments. The directory contents is served via HTTP (see
    # http{} section in config)
    #
    # Incoming stream must be in H264/AAC. For iPhones use baseline H264
    # profile (see ffmpeg example).
    # This example creates RTMP stream from movie ready for HLS:
    #
    # ffmpeg -loglevel verbose -re -i movie.avi  -vcodec libx264
    #    -vprofile baseline -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ac 1
    #    -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/movie
    #
    # If you need to transcode live stream use 'exec' feature.
    #
    application hls {
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_path /tmp/hls;
    }

    # MPEG-DASH is similar to HLS

    application dash {
        live on;
        dash on;
        dash_path /tmp/dash;
    }
}
}

# HTTP can be used for accessing RTMP stats
http {

server {

    listen      8080;

    # This URL provides RTMP statistics in XML
    location /stat {
        rtmp_stat all;

        # Use this stylesheet to view XML as web page
        # in browser
        rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
    }

    location /stat.xsl {
        # XML stylesheet to view RTMP stats.
        # Copy stat.xsl wherever you want
        # and put the full directory path here
        root /path/to/stat.xsl/;
    }

    location /hls {
        # Serve HLS fragments
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }
        root /tmp;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }

    location /dash {
        # Serve DASH fragments
        root /tmp;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }
}
}
```

I am using the `hls` application to stream to. When I view the stream located at `rtmp://ip:1936/hls/test` i can see it fine. When I try and view `http://ip:1936/hls/test.m3u8` I cannot see it. I created a folder in this location for hls `/usr/local/nginx/tmp/hls`. Im wondering if this is in the right place as nothing is being created in the folder? Could it be permission issues?

I am using OBS to stream which uses x246 encoding video but not sure if it's AAC for audio.

A similar issue is being had here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nginx-rtmp/dBKh4akQpcs
but no answer :(.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you content for HLS is over port 8080 and rtmp is over 1936

meaning that rtmp://ip:1936/hls/test 
or http://ip:8080/hls/test.m3u8

Answer (score 1):

I got it fixed by changing to recording, with the following settings:

[image: picture of settings]

next to that, I also changed what JPhix mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

seeing your config, but you place files under /tmp folder not under /usr/local/nginx (full path). If problem persists , an good strategy is start with one application with all of codecs (hls,mpeg-dash) ( like the config examples in github ).

P.D: this module is only for h264 and aac